# UIScrollView not working with Autolayout called from a Tab Bar Controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitabbarcontroller

I have created a very simple test environment one Tab Bar Controller and one View Controller with the following structure:

UI TAB BAR Controller ---------> UIScrollView

UIScrollView
View
  Scroll View
    Label
    Label
    Label

.h file

```
@interface rpViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

@end
```

.m file

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated

{

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 1000);

}
```

If the start entry point for the app is the view with the scroller everything works fine!
If the start entry point is theTab Bar Controller the scroller is not working?

Comment: You shouldn't be setting contentSize with UIScrollView when using auto layout.

Answer (score 2):

If your going to work purely with Autolayout you should not be doing any direct manipulations of frames, bounds or contentSize. Apple has written a technical note about working with [UIScrollView and Autolayout Technical Note TN2154](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html) that you should read.

So to answer the question, if you are going to be using auto layout you cannot manipulate contentSize and expect consistent results.